# Inno Setup How to exclude a single file from AfterInstall

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

After install, I want to save a string to 3 out of the 4 files, but currently it's saving the string to all. How do I exclude a file called network? I'm thinking another `if` statement, but not sure how. This file would be `{app}\configs\network.config`

```pascal
procedure MyBeforeInstall;
begin
  if(FileExists(ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName))) then
  begin
   Exists := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Exists := False;
  end;
end;

procedure MyAfterInstall;
begin
  if not(Exists) then
  SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName), #13#10 + 'SettingEnv       ' + SettingEnv.Values[0] + #13#10, True);
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `MyBeforeInstall` and `MyAfterInstall` like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "*.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  BeforeInstall: MyBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
[Files]
Source: "one.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  BeforeInstall: MyBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall

Source: "two.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  BeforeInstall: MyBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall

Source: "three.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  BeforeInstall: MyBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall

Source: "but_not_this_one.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

---

This will do too:

```
[Files]
Source: "*.txt"; Excludes: "but_no_this_one.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    BeforeInstall: MyBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall

Source: "but_not_this_one.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

---

Yet another option is:

```pascal
procedure MyAfterInstall;
begin
  if CompareText(ExtractFileName(CurrentFileName), 'but_not_this_one.txt') <> 0 then
  begin
    if not Exists then
      SaveStringToFile(
        CurrentFileName,
        #13#10 + 'SettingEnv       ' + SettingEnv.Values[0] + #13#10, True);
  end;
  MsgBox(CurrentFileName, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

*(ntb, that there's no point using `ExpandConstant` on `CurrentFileName`, as its return value does not contain any constants)*

Comment: Last one doesn't save to any file. Second can't create the files. First one works perfectly. That one works best for me anyways since network is the only file I would need to update as well. Since that is the only one I want to update, I used onlyifdoesntexist Flag on the other three files. Would that work or is there a better way of doing it? @martinprikryl

Comment: What does it mean *"Second can't create the files"*? + *"Would that work"* - What would work? I do not understand what you ask for.

Comment: It's fine. I think I got it. I was just wondering if I use the Flag onlyifdoesntexist then files will not be replaced when reinstalling or installing a new version. Thank you! @martinprikryl